# creating new compute instance fails with unknown zone error for 'asia-south1-c'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to GCP so bear with me and forgive my ignorance.

I want to create a new compute instance at `asia-south1` region, I am getting `Unknown zone` error. Following the command that I executed (`asia-south1-c` is my default zone).

```sh
$ gcloud compute instances create app --machine-type=f1-micro
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'zone': 'asia-south1-c'. Unknown zone.
```

The same error is caused by the UI console. I can see the zone available in `gcloud compute zones list`. Don't know what is wrong.

PS: My project was created via Firebase, I created a fresh project but same issue with that as well. I tried successfully with zone `asia-southeast1-a` and `us-west1-a` though.

Comment: can you try providing zone as an argument (--zone)?

Comment: yes i have tried it too.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error after creating a compute instance with the `--zone` flag and then attempting to `describe` or `add-metadata` to it.  The errors went away when I configured gcloud to use the same zone as my compute instance:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone us-west2-b
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially this zone should be visible for all GCP projects. However some GCP users have experienced this `Unknown zone` error caused by an old billing account.

I suggest you to [create](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#create_a_new_billing_account) a new billing account and move a project to it, if the `Unknown zone` error is gone in a project with the new billing account you can move all your projects to that new billing account.

---

Apart from that you could check if there's a Organization Policy restricting that location, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/defining-locations).